# Why do we need "Entities" in DTD's and other places

Tags: html, xml, entity, dtd

I don't understand why we need `!Entities` in DTD's, as well in markup like HTML.

For example, I saw an entity defined as `<!ENTITY copy "©">`.

If we can clearly use the `©` symbol, why do we need to use the entity when using it in markup? Why not just type it in directly as we did here?

Is it a matter of there not being certain symbols on every keyboard? If so, then why do we have an entity for the ampersand when every keyboard has an ampersand.

And one more question - how could the ampersand symbol be used in the definition of ampersand entity!

Would really appreciate if someone could clear up all this confusion for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers do not actually read DTDs. Theoretically, they could, and they may actually do so when processing XML documents, but the entity definitions in HTML specifications are really just a way of describing what notations browsers are supposed to know, as built-in. And naturally XML processors may read DTDs, but I guess that’s a different story.

So this boils down to the question why we would use entity *references* like `&copy;`. Here is a list of possible reasons:

1. When using a non-Unicode character encoding, you need to represent all characters outside the directly representable range using entity references or character references (like `&#xa9;`).
2. You may wish to use an entity reference because you do not have a convenient way of entering a character directly. Quite often, people do this just because they can’t be bothered to learn a way to type special characters.
3. Some characters are invisible or look like a space. The string “1 234” (with a no-break space) is mostly displayed the same way as “1 234” (with a normal space), so writing `1&nbsp;234` would make it much clearer that there is a no-break space.
4. Some characters are difficult to distinguish visually from other, possibly more common characters. Do you see the difference between “−” and “–”? Using `&minus;` and `&ndash;` makes the difference much more prominent in HTML source code.
5. A few characters *must* be written using entity references or character references when they are to appear as data character, at least under some conditions. This applies to `<` and `&` and (withing attribute values) to `"` and `'`.

Regarding `&copy;`, almost always only reason 2 may apply.

The ampersand has an entity, because it opens an entity or character reference, so it may itself need to be “entified” when used as a data character. In HTML specifications, it is formally defined as

```
<!ENTITY amp     CDATA "&#38;">
```

so there is no ambiguity or eternal loop: the entity, like all entities defined in HTML, are defined in terms of character references, which use numbers.

Comment: I thought it's defined as `<!ENTITY amp "&">`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to avoid ugly CDATA sections all over the place, you need an entity for `<`, because that has a special meaning in XML. Given that you need entities in the first place and that they start with `&`, you also need one for that. Then, you need to have a way to put both `'` and `"` inside an attribute value, so you need an entity for at least one of those.

Beyond that, you may need entities (not necessarily named of course, numerical would be fine) if you ever need to transport your data in an encoding that can only transport a subset of Unicode. Unicode encodings, such as UTF-8, are great when you can use them, but that may not always be an option in “the real world.”

Then, Entities do not necessarily stand for a single character either. You could, for example, have your XML files include some text blocks that you have over and over again, by defining them in the DTD and just adding `&legalBlurp;` or `&logo;` in the files themselves. Having this kind of information in a single place to make changes is a good thing.